# Why Tensorflow classification example is not using an activation function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to follow the instructions provided [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) to train a binary classifier and use it for making predictions on new images. As far as I know, a Sigmoid activation function is usually needed at the end of a binary classifier model to limit the outputs to the range between 0 and 1, but this model doesn't have any Softmax or Sigmoid function:

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1)
])
```

When I use the model.predict() command for making predictions on new images, the model returns both positive and negative values which are not limited to any range and I don't have any idea how to interpret them.

I also tried to add a sigmoid activation function to the last Dense layer, *Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'*, but this action drastically reduced the accuracy.

Can someone help me how to understand the output of the model?

Answer (score 2):

Default activation function for `Dense` layer is the linear function. If you follow the tutorial, you will observe that they compile the model using a `CrossEntropy` loss with `from_logits = True` argument. This is such that raw predictions from the `Dense(1)` layer are converted to the class probabilities according to [logits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) when the loss is calculated.

If you switch the activation to `sigmoid` you should modify your loss function with `from_logits=False` accordingly, so that the loss function expects values in the range of [0,1]

The reason why `from_logits=True` is used in the tutorial is that it can produce more [numerically stable results](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy?hl=en) (According to TF)